I was solving fluctuating load problems and the word "static" confused me

Here's a snippet of the question that was asked a couple of years ago in university exam:
A cantilever beam made of cold rolled steel for which ultimate tensile strength =540 MPa and Yield tensile strength = 360 Mpa. the expected reliability is 90% and Fos =1.8. Find diameter d for a> infinite life for load of +- 125N and b> use static approach where P varies from -125N to 125N. In both cases I am getting the same answer ie:11.49 ~ 12mm.
My approach for the first question was: find the bending moment at the fillet= 12500Nmm and then use the factors to find out corrected endurance limit which came to be = 150.79 Mpa. and from there I used sigma endurance / fos = 32xMb/(pi x d^3)
PLease help

Isn't the static approach just about simple strength without considering fatigue?

i thought so too, just consider the least csa and design but when I told my prof, he denied saying it's about finite life and it makes no sense
